# How can i make semi circle type menu which should be scrollable for iPhone/iPad?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios4, uiscrollview

[image]

Hi I want to make such kind of menu for my iPhone/iPad Application but i don't have any idea about it so please help me and guide me how can i make this kind of menu and what should i use for that?

Comment: I haven't seen anything like this on the iPhone yet - I guess (as you certainly know) because it's rather complicated and requires lots of work compared to using a standard build in menu solution. But I am sure once this is done many others would like to have something fancy like this too. It's your choice to make it freely available and then see many of us using it.... (I know this is not really an anwswer - but probably a motivation to do it!)

Comment: ok thanks for that.I know you can do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple idea of implementing is: ROTATE YOUR VIEWS according to the touches on iPhone